# Live_helpers function usage in liveview app "live_beats" by chrismccord

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

There is a function sidebar_account_dropdown/1 in lib/live_beats_web/views/layout_view.ex

```
def sidebar_account_dropdown(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <.dropdown id={@id}>
      <:img src={@current_user.avatar_url}/>
      <:title><%= @current_user.name %></:title>
      <:subtitle>@<%= @current_user.username %></:subtitle>

      <:link navigate={profile_path(@current_user)}>View Profile</:link>
      <:link navigate={Routes.settings_path(Endpoint, :edit)}>Settings</:link>
      <:link href={Routes.o_auth_callback_path(Endpoint, :sign_out)} method={:delete}>Sign out</:link>
    </.dropdown>
    """
end
```

And in its template part dropdown function from lib/live_beats_web/live/live_helpers.ex

```
def dropdown(assigns) do
    assigns =
      assigns
      |> assign_new(:img, fn -> nil end)
      |> assign_new(:title, fn -> nil end)
      |> assign_new(:subtitle, fn -> nil end)

    ~H"""
    <!-- User account dropdown -->
    <div class="px-3 mt-6 relative inline-block text-left">
```

> just not to elongate things I cutted the long dropdown function
> [dropdown/1](https://github.com/fly-apps/live_beats/blob/337931e21e46de2a1d5e02d1855e380a57ec9945/lib/live_beats_web/live/live_helpers.ex#L174)

I would like to know how the html tags are replaced with atoms.
Is it used as a means for assigning value to the :img, :title, :subtitle,  etc that exist in our assigns as nil or something.
I would love to understand this clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoenix Liveview defines its own [engine](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.HTMLEngine.html) for [`sigil_H/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.Helpers.html#sigil_H/2).

The engine has its own tokenizer which understands `<.` opening, treats is [as a slot](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view/blob/v0.17.7/lib/phoenix_live_view/html_engine.ex#L161-L169) and processes further.

Comment: Okay but how are the html tags <img>,<title> used as <:img>,<:title> in sidebar_account_dropdown function. Is this making any difference?

Comment: Once again: all these “tags” are under `sigil_H/1` and get processed by this sigil extrapolation as I showed in the linked code.

Comment: thank you so much 
Now I have better understanding of the usage of slots
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.Component.html#module-slots